# sqlautocode for mysql giving syntax error

Tags: python, web-applications, turbogears2

I am using TG2.1 on WinXP.
Python ver is 2.6.
Trying to use sqlautocode (0.5.2) for working with my existing MySQL schema.
SQLAlchemy ver is 0.6.6

> > import sqlautocode  # works OK

While trying to reflect the schema ----

> > sqlautocode mysql:\\username:pswd@hostname:3306\schema_name -o tables.py

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
is raised.

Can someone please point out what's going wrong, & how to handle the same?

Thanks,
Vineet.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue may be the backslash "\" Try going from this:

```
sqlautocode mysql:\\username:pswd@hostname:3306\schema_name -o tables.py
```

to this:

```
sqlautocode mysql://username:pswd@hostname:3306/schema_name -o tables.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey, I got it right somehow.
The problem seems to be version mismatch between SA 0.6 & sqlautocode 0.6
Seems that they don't work in tandom.
So I removed those & installed SA 0.5

Now it's working.

Thanks,
Vineet Deodhar.